# 18.04 HDMI Sound not working

Tags: sound, multiple-monitors, hdmi

Going through the threads I see many unresolved issues with HDMI sound.  Tried many of the suggested fixes.
My HDMI TV display is working fine:

with xrandr I get this:

```
HDMI-1-1 connected primary

**xrandr --output HDMI-1-1 --set audio on**

warning: output HDMI-1-1 not found; ignoring
X Error of failed request:  BadRROutput (invalid Output parameter)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  15 (RRGetOutputProperty)
  Serial number of failed request:  45
  Current serial number in output stream:  45
```

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes have trouble with my HDMI audio, and I've found that using `pavucontrol` works reliably.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
pavucontrol
```

Comment: I used pavucontrol, the HDMI device is not listed there

Comment: your HDMI output isn't listed? It should be even if it's not plugged in. On my system it's like `Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (HDMI)`

Comment: I have one not HDMI though: Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (IEC958). On the same system booting with a Live USB HDMI sound output shows up  shows up and works. the installation was done with WUBI could that cause issues?